# Query object with a timestamp in NSDate from Realm DB

Tags: objective-c, timestamp, realm, nsdate

I try to get an object from Realm with a certain timestamp, but I get no result. This is a piece of code I use:

```
- (void) sendMediaChatMessage {
    //...
    NSLog(@"NSDate to string: %@", message.timeStamp);// is NSDate object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [ [ NSDateFormatter alloc ] init ];
    [ dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS" ];
    NSString *stringDate = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ dateFormat stringFromDate:message.timeStamp ] ];
    NSLog(@"Timestamp to string: %@", stringDate);
    //...
}

// When receiving chat message
- (void) updateChatStatusWithTimestamp: (NSDate*) timestamp withStatus: (ChatMessageStatus) state {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [ [ NSDateFormatter alloc ] init ];
    [ dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS" ];
    NSString *stringDate = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ dateFormat stringFromDate: timestamp ] ];
    NSLog(@"Reversed dateformat: %@", stringDate);
    NSLog(@"NSDate to string: %@", timestamp);

    NSPredicate *pred = [ NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeStamp == %@", timestamp ];
    RLMResults<RLMChatMessage *> *results = [ RLMChatMessage objectsWithPredicate: pred ];

    NSLog(@"Found chat items with the same timestamp: %lu", (unsigned long)results.count);
}
```

The NSLog output is as follows:

...when sending

2017-06-21 14:21:56.468224 sendChatMessage:

2017-06-21 14:21:56.468664 NSDate to string: Wed Jun 21 14:21:56 2017

2017-06-21 14:21:56.470802 Timestamp to string: 20170621122156430

2017-06-21 14:21:56.471445 With message: Hello world

2017-06-21 14:21:56.471922 Sending to user: android

2017-06-21 14:21:56.586503 Received Msg objects from server...

2017-06-21 14:21:56.586684 handleChatMessage

2017-06-21 14:21:56.586854 Type of message: 2

2017-06-21 14:21:56.586903 Chat destination: transformers

2017-06-21 14:21:56.586936 Timestamp: 20170621122156430

2017-06-21 14:21:56.588515 Latitude: xx.906111

2017-06-21 14:21:56.588746 Longitude: xx.476332

...when received

2017-06-21 14:21:56.590504 Reversed dateformat: 20170621142156430

2017-06-21 14:21:56.590602 NSDate to string: Wed Jun 21 14:21:56 2017

2017-06-21 14:21:56.591470 Found chat items with the same timestamp: 0

I assume something has to do with the timezone. But I  don't know how to fix this. So, what could be another reason why Realm can't find an object with passed timestamp?

Comment: I see Timestamp show different hours is a difference in timezone, I send time in UTC+0, but on receiving, I converted in local time. Printing straight from NSDate shows local time.

Comment: Can you please instead print out the date's `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` in both cases? That will show the point in time that the `NSDate` represents. `NSDate` itself refers to a specific point in time independent of any time zone. The formatted string representations bring time zones into the mix, which just adds an extra possibility for confusion.

Comment: I'll do it next time, I fixed it by adding a timestamp field with a string instead of NSDate. But as soon as I have the time, I'll try to fix it to use NSDate only. I couldn't really find a proper way to convert NSDate into string, send over the network and than on the other side convert string into NSDate to get the same result as the original.

Comment: The string representation you were using dropped time zone information, which likely lead to each side interpreting the string representation in their local time zone. If the time zones are different on device vs server, you'd get an unexpected result. Using a string date format like ISO8601 would preserve full fidelity of the time.